# Magento cart can only take one item (1 quantity per product)

Tags: magento

I'm working on a page with Magento!
When I try to Add to my Card a product with quantity more than 1, it comes to my Card with quantity 1...
How can this problem be solved???

Comment: Without providing us any of the code you're working on, all we could do is guess.

Comment: There is any cofiguration for solving that problem?

Comment: That sounds clearly like it isn't the intended behavior of Magento, so it's likely you've done something wrong. "Something" is all I can narrow down your issue to, though, without seeing any of what you're doing.

Comment: I am doing that thing that could be done with Magento.

Comment: I don't know how else to tell you this - you **need to post code** if you want people to be able to help you with this. I'm done otherwise.

Comment: I can't post all my code here. I even don't know which part of the code has the problem and how to solve that? My answer is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38523/magento-cart-can-only-take-one-item-1-quantity-per-product

There are 2 qty input field on your page that been submitted see debug below.

You need to remove one of them

[image]